# Get a variable as filename from python script and use it in a batch script

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a python script which gives the output as: The lastest filename of a directory.

I want to use this filename in a batch script. How can i able to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the output of a command with a `for /f` loop:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command') do set "var=%%a"
```

replace `command` with your phyton script.

Note: as written, the variable will contain the last line (or only one) of the output.

Note: this is batch file syntax. If you use it directly on command line, replace every `%%a` with `%a`

Comment: My latest file is "Business Component.xlsx". my python code gives the below path:              
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('removeLatest.py') do set "var=%%a"
echo %var%
SET cmd="for /F %%i in ("%var%") do @echo %%~ni"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('%cmd%') do SET arg1=%%a
ECHO "%arg1%"

ECHO "%arg1%"                                                                                                                                 But this gives the output as : Business but my requirement is to get the filename without extension i.e "Business Component"

Comment: Don't forget `"delims="` for your second `for` loop, or it will give you just the part before the first space. Alternatively you can `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('removeLatest.py') do set "var=%%~na"

Comment: for /f "delims=" %%a in ('removeLatest.py') do set "var=%%~na"
    SET cmd="for /F %%i in ("%var%") do @echo %%~ni" 
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%b in ('%cmd%') do SET arg1=%%b 
    ECHO "%arg1%"                  -  This code gives the output as "Business ". Is there any way i can fetch the filename from a path variable. For ex: path="C:/Users/Documents/file name.xlsx" i want to get the o/p as : "file name"

Comment: The solution worked for me. Thanks for your help. All the best.