# Generate a list of file names of certain type with hash values comma separated with bat or ps1 script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, hash

I'm trying to get a list of files of the type .zip with hash value (SHA256) in csv using a bat script or a ps1 script.

In bat script I've:

```
@echo off
set "zipfiles=C:\Location\*.zip"
for %%f in (%zipfiles%) do (
set filename=%%f
set hash=certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256
echo %filename%, %hash% >> C:\Location\Report\ListOfFiles.csv
)
```

My result in csv is:

```
SHA256 hash of C:\Location\File 00001.zip:
61b22633916abe04a9024f852f5d873b79635cff75ffc8a36377faa59593369a
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
SHA256 hash of C:\Location\File 00002.zip:
e9cdc01a70ce0f2f1fbd8b9e94530fac105609d918858c944d1b8ee3a50764ad
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
SHA256 hash of C:\Location\File 00003.zip:
68b17a9d0d98dd64f3c6c5b29e5cd304a6397d21f24e3087723ccad9f6f77c58
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
```

Desired result in csv is:

```
File 00001.zip, 61b22633916abe04a9024f852f5d873b79635cff75ffc8a36377faa59593369a
File 00002.zip, e9cdc01a70ce0f2f1fbd8b9e94530fac105609d918858c944d1b8ee3a50764ad
File 00003.zip, 68b17a9d0d98dd64f3c6c5b29e5cd304a6397d21f24e3087723ccad9f6f77c58
```

In ps1 script I've so far

```
param(
      [string] $padstaging = 'C:\Location\',
      [string] $padreport = 'C:\Location\Report',
            
      [string] $output = $padreport+'ListOfFiles.csv'
      )

Get-Childitem -Path $padstaging -Recurse | where {!$_.PSIsContainer} | select-object FullName | export-csv -path $output -Delimiter ',' -notypeinformation;
```

But how do I add the file names to the output?

Comment: `set hash=certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256` does not what you are trying to do, namely to assign the output of `certutil` to variable `hash`; you'll need a [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) to accomplish this: `for /F "delims=" %%h in ('certutil -hashfile "%%~f" SHA256 ^| find /V ":"') do set "hash=%%h"` (`find` is there to just capture the hash)…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the lack of [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), the second problem is you can't assign the output of a command to a variable like you tried. You'd need [another `for` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52691255/2152082). But you can avoid both problems with a little trick to write without a line feed:

```
(for %%f in (%zipfiles%) do (
  <nul set /p =%%f,
  certutil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256|find /v ":" || echo empty file
))> "C:\Location\Report\ListOfFiles.csv"
```

If a file is empty (zero bytes), `certutil` has nothing to work with and gives an error. In this case, `|| echo empty file` echoes a string (and of course the `CRLF` to end the line)

Comment: just a small additional question, how do I put %%f in dubble quotes in the output file, like "File 00001.zip", 61b22633916abe04a9024f852f5d873b79635cff75ffc8a36377faa59593369a

Comment: @Gideon, change `set /p =%%f,` to `set /p =""%%f","` (the outer pair of `""` is removed by `set /p`)…